# Code Golf Banner

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Ouput the following banner:

```
   _____          _         _____       _  __ 
  / ____|        | |       / ____|     | |/ _|
 | |     ___   __| | ___  | |  __  ___ | | |_ 
 | |    / _ \ / _` |/ _ \ | | |_ |/ _ \| |  _|
 | |___| (_) | (_| |  __/ | |__| | (_) | | |  
  \_____\___/ \__,_|\___|  \_____|\___/|_|_|
```

The code that has the fewest bytes wins! I'm interested to see what clever formulas some of you come up with, bare in mind I just created this in notepad with no clever formula in mind so you may not be likely in finding one.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! *you may not be likely in finding one.* - haha, we always do :)

Comment: On the scale of humanity I consider myself good at maths - but it still always amazes me :)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm afraid this looks far too similar to an older challenge for me to leave open. There isn't much difference even in the character sets used in the questions, you just have an extra comma and a backtick. To try to avoid things like this, I'd recommend the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2140/31625) for your future challenges.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 128 bytes

```
“UyɠȯaẹṇṾƊSḳẋƘø;ṫṃ42MọẆẇB3tʂñṅƈṠUẈṣcC\ÑḢ¦¿$Ọỵịnß⁻ȥ2¶ø⁸Ḥ¢ȮN÷ẹƘḣƘßFĠC⁸⁴ʠe'ȮƊẹġƒhSṅsɼĖḟṘʋÆỌVKɠeḌ⁽ṗ?=ƈƥḍP⁴ĿḳaɲƬ*ṪñṪ’ṃ“_/|\`( ),”s46Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/PSwJBFMfv/hVzCNIQFky6RAQJXaIIxCBYWCOECOliF2EObpGKPw51KIPCTbODhdHvmd1K2F0G9b94@49sMztqzuHNe@/z3ve9d5jJZvO@7xVuUvmhMXjeA5MCLQH9ZZUkkDcwq6zhkGWgj0BP47FNsOpgFsEsrS0ej06cF6BnrAzUSIHJv/Z@QnXOgbTsB7s/B1YNrA@wqkdO09OtQSdmfzrE0wmQe7s16G05X3wcawBp8yHNdddIcOjp7yMjMz/osQqn7h27OEjyKbnht3sJpAm0Mao6Ra69szE0MkBqnv4D9Gp1hZVZB0h9mwu4fb773vCVPS0A7Yotu17hml/AD9UUrKbDKBL1Cre5@NKu7/sIIU08NH3/7izQRIhCCClBGk9qMJq4s4BneYhDUyyFBMbSD4CmSSICLNTH5bwXqcKmAx3ujytkJHulejAyrEWQsGNRRQKMJiTI893V4CJhFeFHNazKlSUIIgVrWKT@AA)

This is just a direct compression, no tricks :).

Comment: Only a single comma - save a byte with `“ı<ƇŒṃ¹Ḅzs:"ḳ'/sṀ6%Ðæẏŀ®4²ɱ⁼aṢ%®ƬIẒḢaŀ¡ʂĠɲ\ḢḂġṁDṭỵþ[ỴUzg⁽ȯṄẸa⁶XñṂ®ṄrTÇƊv?iḅozṁJhḢỵw⁴ṛFjĊ¬Ɲ¿PṿdƘ⁼¢fƘmṪṇȯ>B’ṃ“ /|\`()_”s46Y”,-27¦`

Comment: ...infact only a single backtick too, so save another two with: `“Ṣ<ⱮL¶(ædẓ¹-ėȯ£IḍṄØ0!ḍḢṭẊƁ⁺-ȥ?½ƝṙOṬiŒɓỊoŻị~Çẉ®6⁺K@Ṃn\`ẸṄɲWb°⁵Ƥ2¶ẓ^&ṪḳyBẈẸŀṪM¦ọĠKṚṃƙ}¦Ṛ²Ỵœ⁴>0B⁸3ạ1¥ɓ’ṃ“ /|\()_”s46Y”,-27¦”\`159¦`

Comment: Why are downvotes being given for a valid answer posted before this question was marked as a duplicate?